# Phonegap - Barcode scanner plugin - Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

Hi I am currently developing a phone gap bar code scanner and will be supported across a number of devices.

I am using the plugin https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner and I have it working perfectly on Android but I need to get it working on windows phone 8.1. On the windows phone, nothing happens when I click the link. On android it launchs the scanner and can read the barcode. Below is the code I am using. The results of the barcode are appended to the results divs.

**Here is the JS**

document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);

function init() {

```
document.querySelector("#startScan").addEventListener("touchend", startScan, false);
resultDiv1 = document.querySelector("#results1");
```

}

function startScan() {

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +

  }, 
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  }
```

);

}

As I said, this works perfectly on Android. Is there something different I need to try to get it working on the windows phone?

Comment: have you read this https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/issues/172